# Using jquery to add/remove class but elements are not redrawn to reflect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, repaint

I have two elements (think of two buttons side by side). I dynamically toggle the class "focusd" to change the highlighted effect. However, there's a quirk it doesn't always get redrawn and/or inserted in the DOM. For example, if in chrome I do console.log, I see the class changes (I'm using removeClass/addClass in jquery). But if I go to the Elements tab in the inspector, it shows the classes from before (and in fact, I'm not seeing the redrawing reflecting the toggling of the classes.)

I tried setting the parent div to display none then back to block but that didn't work. It's a "one off" modale screen, so efficiency doesn't matter so I've resorted to this hack where I essentially copy the parent's innerhtml, remove and reinsert the element. Horrible!

```
       // Not sure why I need this hack. But if I don't, the buttons don't seem to get redrawn 
       var htm  = jQuery(".rdata_container").html(); // copy the  innerhtml
       jQuery(".rdata_container").empty();           // empty and then append back
       jQuery(".rdata_container").append(htm);
```

This seems like a specific quirk that someone must have ran into (I hope). If so, I'd love to know why my changes aren't reflected.

**EDIT** 
Code posted here:
http://jsfiddle.net/roblevintennis/JCZnf/

Comment: Most likely it's a bug in your code.

Comment: Can you add the code in jsfiddle.net? The addClass and removeClass should work.

Comment: I believe the problem lies in some other part of your code.

Comment: @Brian: Yah, you're likely correct. Unfortunately, there a lot of odd interactions since it's for a connect TV env. In any event, posted the code line per @ngen's suggestion.

Comment: That jsfiddle is not useful, as it does nothing at all. The code you put there isn't adequate to demonstrate the problem. You didn't even set it up to use jQuery!

Comment: "it doesn't always get redrawn" what does it refer to? Are you wanting a modal box to go away and return?  When I click 'Ok' then what do you want to happen?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `setTimeout` when you are doing the other operation on the element, so for example:

```
$elm.addClass('hide')
setTimeout(function(){
  $elm.removeCalss('hide')
},0);
```

Or you could force a repaint like so:

```
$elm.addClass('hide')
$elm.scrollTop; // forces a repaint (might be expensive for large amount of items)
$elm.removeCalss('hide');
```

These tricks will force the browser to re-draw the change, because there are two things happening here and the browser logic just combines them into one, which isn't the desired behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Not directly an answer to your question, but you can use [jQuery's toggleClass function](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to simplify your code.

Here's an updated version that uses toggleClass() and jQuery 1.6 and AFAICT works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/JCZnf/7/